# Why doesn't the label "version" appear in running pod json?

Tags: kubernetes, label

`kubectl get pod pod_name -n namespace_name -o json` shows:

```
"labels": {
    "aadpodidbinding": "sa-customerxyz-uat-msi",
    "app": "cloudsitemanager",
    "customer": "customerxyz",
    "istio.io/rev": "default",
    "pod-template-hash": "b87d9fcbf",
    "security.istio.io/tlsMode": "istio",
    "service.istio.io/canonical-name": "cloudsitemanager",
    "service.istio.io/canonical-revision": "latest"
}
```

I am deploying with the following manifest yaml snippet:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: cloudsitemanager
  labels:
    app: cloudsitemanager
    customer: customerxyz
    version: 0.1.0-beta.201
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: cloudsitemanager
      customer: customerxyz
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: cloudsitemanager
        customer: customerxyz
        version: 0.1.0-beta.201
        aadpodidbinding: sa-customerxyz-uat-msi
```

I expect to see 4 custom labels in the running pod manifest:  app, customer, version, aadpodidbinding.  However, I only see 3 of the custom labels.  The label "version" does not show.

Comment: Which kubernetes version are you using? Have you tried labeling your test deployment with `kubectl label deployment test version=0.1.0-beta.201`

Comment: K8s version 1.19.3

Comment: `kubectl label deployment cloudsitemanager version=0.1.0-beta.201`
error: 'version' already has a value (0.1.0-beta.201), and --overwrite is false


So K8s sees the "version" label.  But "version" is not listed in the labels: section.

Also, I cannot use the label version.  Example:
`kubectl get pods -l customer=customerxyz` shows the running pods.
`kubectl get pods -l version=0.1.0-beta.201` does not find any running pods
No resources found in sa-customerxyz-uat-aks1 namespace.

Comment: How exactly are you creating this `Deployment`? Is it with the `$ kubectl xxx -f name.yaml` command or in other way? Could you share the whole `Deployment` definition (without PII) for recreation purposes?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with running Istio + Kiali as Kiali was not showing the version. I tried adding the "version" label under the spec of the Deployment but it didn't work. After adding the "version" label for the POD's spec (.spec.template.metadata.labels) it started applying the "version" labels for the newly created pod and Kiali now shows the version number instead of "latest"

Comment: I confirm the warning disappears if we add "version" in "Deployment": spec.template.metadata.labels.version: 0.0.1-beta

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue since I was using kustomize to apply labels in kustomization.yaml, had to add additional `includeTemplates: true` property for lables to apply to pod templates as well.

```yaml
labels:
- pairs:
    version: 1.0.122
  includeTemplates: true
```